# Jinja2 in google appengine extended template repeates base templete

Tags: google-app-engine, templates, loops, jinja2

Ok I have a base.html and I try to use that for my header menu and footer. In my other template I loop over items and display them on the page. My problem is the the other template is repeating my base.html like it's in the loop. I hope someone can show me the error in My ways.

Here is my base.html code:

```
 <div class="menu">
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/newpost">New Entry</a></li>
    <li><a href="/signup">Sign-up</a></li>
    {% if user %}
    <li>{{user.name}}</li>
    <li><a href="/logout">Log-Out</a></li>
    {% else %}
    <li><a href="/login">Log-In</a></li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
```

​

This is in the base.html also but didn't paste correctly.

```
<div id="content">
  {% block content %}
  {% endblock %}
  </div>
```

And here is the sub template code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
  {% for p in posts %}
    {{ p.render() | safe }}
    <br><br>
  {% endfor %}
    <div>
        {{text}}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Please help
Edit:
edit2: removed link and found my problem I was calling the wrong html file in render()
Be kind Newbie here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks ok.  Are you sure you don't have a loop in the python code that renders the template?

Comment: No p.render() loops but just to change \n to <br> And LiNk to <a> tags

Comment: Can you post the code for the function that renders the entire template?

Comment: Yeah, you can't format code in a comment, usu you would edit the original question and put it in htere.  I don't see the template rendering code in there though.

Comment: `def get(self):
        posts = top()
        timedcache = time.time()-cache['timer']        
        text = 'Queried %f seconds ago'%timedcache   
        self.render('front.html', posts = posts, text = text)`

Comment: everything looks ok... you might want to double check those redirects to see if you end up re-rendering the output during the redirection.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help edit: I don't have enough rep to vote you up for helping